# Why I can't print pages correctly in the StackExchange platform

Tags: support, printing

This is the actual page, for example:

> [image: Chemistry]:

But when I try to print it this is what I get:

> [image: print preview]

You can see that the page was narrowed.

It happens in any question in this site. If I try to print it horizontally, some of the lines are disappear. I have tried all ready in many computers and in all of them the problem exist!

I usually print the questions I'm asking since it's more convenient for me to read from a paper, only recently this problem occurred.